# Correct way of getting a Json position

Tags: android, json

After the login I get this response from the webserver..

```
{"success":" Bem vindo lu@lu.com"}{"nomeusuario":"Lu Zimermann"}{"enderecousuario":"Rua Pedro Alves 270. Centro. Casa."}{"telefoneusuario":"(42) 3623-8052"}
```

Ok. Now My android code.

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Restaurantes.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
```

This code Toast the following message.  "Bem vindo lu@lu.com"

What I want is:
How can I get the other infos and pass it to a String.

Email = "lu@lu.com"

Endereco = "Rua Pedro..."

Name = "Lu Zimermann"

Soo I can use it later on the app.

Thanks.

Comment: First try to edit back end code that server returns the response in a `JSONArray`, so that each `JSONObject` can be parsed properly..

Comment: Or you could pass the data itself in a single `JSONObject`

Comment: Try to code on server side to response as `{"success":" Bem vindo lu@lu.com","nomeusuario":"Lu Zimermann","enderecousuario":"Rua Pedro Alves 270. Centro. Casa.","telefoneusuario":"(42) 3623-8052"}`

Comment: got it. the server side is responding right as you said now.

Comment: As i saw your json response is not valid

Comment: I would suggest to use Gson for parsing Json. It's pretty easy and very very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the response is the right way you can do this to save data.. 
first wirte a custion class for Preferennce

**SharedPreferenceCustom**

```
public class SharedPreferenceCustom {
    private Context mContext;
    private String defValue = "";

    public SharedPreferenceCustom(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setSharedPref(String inputKey, Object inputValue) {
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(inputKey, String.valueOf(inputValue));
        editor.apply();

    }

    public String getSharedPref(String inputKey) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(inputKey, defValue);
    }
}
```

Now for saving the data, in the activity

```
 try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(new String(response_from_server))
    SharedPreferenceCustom sp = new SharedPreferenceCustom(Activity.this); 
    sp.setSharedPref("key_1", response.getString("nomeusuario"));   // use key as per needed   
    sp.setSharedPref("key_2", response.getString("enderecousuario"));
    sp.setSharedPref("key_3", response.getString("telefoneusuario"));
    sp.setSharedPref("key_4", response.getString("success"));  
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And for getting the data call `sp.getSharedPref("key");` pass the key for getting the corresponding data

**EDIT:** you can also write individual function in `SharedPreferenceCustion` to store different data type, or you can use just this, But it might create some conflicts for certain data types,

Hope this helps :) :)

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the other keys, you can use the `get(key)` on the `jsonObject` object. Here are the code changes you need to make:

```
     try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                {"success":" Bem vindo lu@lu.com"}{"nomeusuario":"Lu Zimermann"}{"enderecousuario":"Rua Pedro Alves 270. Centro. Casa."}{"telefoneusuario":"(42) 3623-8052"}
                //here I am just getting the other properties/keys
                String nomeusuario = jsonObject.getString("nomeusuario");
                String enderecousuario = jsonObject.getString("enderecousuario");
                String telefoneusuario = jsonObject.getString("telefoneusuario");

                //here you could do whatever you like - I am just making a Toast as an example:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nomeusuario+ ", "+enderecousuario+ ", "+telefoneusuario ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I hope this helps you - give it a try and let me know.
By the way, I am assuming the JSON that you are getting is proper.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do that.

First of all you need to store them into variable/s. 
You can choose to keep it as JSON var, as HashMap or each variable separate as String.

The second action is to access it from any place. This depends on how long to you want the information alive. 
If you want them live for just as long as the app is live then the I suggest to create a Global Java class with set/get of your variable.
You could also store it in SharedPreferences or sqlite database for permanent.

Comment: I will use the SharedPreferences. But still. How can I get the name and the address from the Json?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
                            String values = "";
                            while(keys.hasNext()){
                                String keyName = keys.next();
                                values = jsonObject.getString(keyName) + "\n";
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),values,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                           
                          //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Restaurantes.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
```